# Voting on Catalyst with multiple wallets

Tags: catalyst, yoroi

I have created multiple Yoroi wallets to share ADA with family members. We would like to use the sum of ADAs to participate in the next voting round in Catalyst. Can we do that or is your number of ADA wallet specific?

Comment: It always is whatever you have one on one wallet. So you can all each vote separately but all would need to use their own QR codes and vote for the same thing. There isn't a way to pool ADA just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each wallet will represent its own amount of ADA and will have its own representation for voting.  You won't be able to pool the amounts together and will have to register each wallet to vote independently.

Answer (score 0):

You need a certain amount of Ada to participate in voting. Your voting power increases with the amount of Ada you own, one wallet does not equal one vote.